# Adjust the html page under the last tag

Tags: html, resize

i have created a html page and i have a problem. The footer is the last tag i have on page and there is a blank under that. I want to adjust the page so that there is no blank under it.

Comment: Please share a code snippet

Answer (score 1):

**You should try this** `<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px">`

It is saved in the default browser stylesheets `<body style="margin:4px; padding:4px">`.

You can change the default browser stylesheets, but you shouldn't. It differs with each browser. Google it! How do I change the default stylesheet on ?
There probably are slight differences, you should be able to tell... by looking at the default stylesheets :)
That difference is one of the main reasons we as designers use a CSS reset, to normalize all of the CSS awkwardness that follows different browser implementations.